# How to get strongest path prolog?

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, shortest-path

I'm trying to create a social graph and I have to write some Prolog in order to get the minimal and the strongest path.

My knowledge base only has the following statements:

edge(source, destination, weight)

example: (john, mary, 2).

The weights can only be 3 for now:

1 - Friend
2-  Close friend
3 - Family

Here is my code to the minimal path (less weighted).

```
findapath(X, Y, W, [X,Y], _) :- edge(X, Y, W).
findapath(X, Y, W, [X|P], V) :- \+ member(X, V),
                                 edge(X, Z, W1),
                                 findapath(Z, Y, W2, P, [X|V]),
                                 W is W1 + W2.

:-dynamic(solution/2).
findminpath(X, Y, W, P) :- \+ solution(_, _),
                           findapath(X, Y, W1, P1, []),
                           assertz(solution(W1, P1)),
                           !,
                           findminpath(X,Y,W,P).

findminpath(X, Y, _, _) :- findapath(X, Y, W1, P1, []),
                           solution(W2, P2),
                           W1 < W2,
                           retract(solution(W2, P2)),
                           asserta(solution(W1, P1)),
                           fail.

findminpath(_, _, W, P) :- solution(W,P), retract(solution(W,P)).
```

How to include a variable to count the number of paths traveled and then use that to get the strongest path?

The strongest path is path weight / number of paths traveled.

So for example,

Weight = 8
N Paths traveled = 3

8/3 = 2.67 strength

Which means that there are 3 people between me and my destination (this is a social graph) and their weighted sum is 8.

But in this case

Weight = 7
N Paths traveled = 7

This would be the minimal path instead, right? YES, because it's 7 and 7 < 8. However, it is  NOT the strongest path because 7/7 = 1 and that means that I probably had loads of people between me and my destination that weren't as close to me as the other path.

How would I do this?

Comment: using assert/retract to do inferences is bad design, try to avoid it...